# Is there an alternative of RewriteRule / .htaccess for a Python http.server.HTTPServer?

Tags: python, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

Can my server module (with `http.server.HTTPServer`) use something like the  `RewriteRule` for redirect all traffic into a single cgi script? I'd like to be able to do what's shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200161/how-to-hide-a-subfolder-in-url-rewriting) in this other question, but for my python server.

Can it be done using something like `.htaccess`, or is there another way?

Also, can this be done even for a simple localhost development server?
I am serving files for development via, for example, http://localhost:8000/html/index.html, and I would like to hide the /html subfolder from the URL even in development. 
How can that be achieved?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Apache's mod_rewrite has nothing to do with python.

Comment: i'm asking for something like mod_rewrite in http.server python :)

Comment: Hey @fj123x I was wondering if you found my answer helpful

Answer (score 9):

You can use a custom script to initialize your server and define your **Routes** in it, such as suggested in [this article](https://www.huyng.com/posts/modifying-python-simplehttpserver):

**Python 2:**

> `server.py`
>
> ```
> import os
> import posixpath
> import urllib
> import BaseHTTPServer
> from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
>
> # modify this to add additional routes
> ROUTES = (  <- this is the "good stuff", make aliases for your paths
>     # [url_prefix ,  directory_path]
>     ['/media', '/var/www/media'],
>     ['',       '/var/www/site']  # empty string for the 'default' match
> ) 
>
> class RequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
>
>     def translate_path(self, path):
>         """translate path given routes"""
>
>         # set default root to cwd
>         root = os.getcwd()
>
>         # look up routes and set root directory accordingly
>         for pattern, rootdir in ROUTES:
>             if path.startswith(pattern):
>                 # found match!
>                 path = path[len(pattern):]  # consume path up to pattern len
>                 root = rootdir
>                 break
>
>         # normalize path and prepend root directory
>         path = path.split('?',1)[0]
>         path = path.split('#',1)[0]
>         path = posixpath.normpath(urllib.unquote(path))
>         words = path.split('/')
>         words = filter(None, words)
>
>         path = root
>         for word in words:
>             drive, word = os.path.splitdrive(word)
>             head, word = os.path.split(word)
>             if word in (os.curdir, os.pardir):
>                 continue
>             path = os.path.join(path, word)
>
>         return path
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     BaseHTTPServer.test(RequestHandler, BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer)
> ```

Then run your script:

```
python server.py
```

**Python 3:**

In Python 3 the `BaseHTTPServer` and the `SimpleHTTPServer` modules have been merged into the `http.server` module. So you will have to modify the above script as follows:

Change the

```
import BaseHTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
```

to

```
import http.server
```

*(if you do this then the calls should be modified to `http.server.SimpleHTTPRequest` etc.)*

or

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
```

*(with this option calls remain the same as the original script)*

then run the server script: `python server.py`

---

**IN YOUR CASE:**

You should modify the `ROUTES` variable to suite your needs. 
For example, you want to hide the `/html` folder from your url:

```
ROUTES = (
    ['', '/exact/path/to/folder/html'],
    ['/another_url_path', '/exact/path/to/another/folder'],
    ...
)
```

Now if you hit: `http://localhost:8000/index.html` you will be in your home page.

---

**Note:**

This script by default will serve the contained files in the folder that is in when executed to the *domain url* (ex. I have `server.py` on the Documents folder, then when I run it, http://localhost:8000 url will server my Documents folder). 
You can change this behavior by the Routes (see the 'default' match comment on the code) or by placing the script in your projects root folder and start it from there.

Answer (score 2):

[John Moutafis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43342792/13241963) was helpful to get me started, but needed some fine tuning to run on python3, beyond his comments about imports.

The imports should be

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
```

and you'll also need to change the urllib import to:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
```

Then the main should be something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    myServer = HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8000), RequestHandler)
    print("Ready to begin serving files.")
    try:
        myServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    myServer.server_close()
    print("Exiting.")
```