# How to hide a subfolder in url rewriting

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My site is : www.mysite.com/subfolder/login/index.php

I want the URL there to just be `www.mysite.com/login/index.php`. I tried modifying the .htaccess file in the root folder as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^login\/index\.php$ /subfolder/login/index.php [L]
```

--but the problem is that then it can't use or access the CSS file (style.css) from the login folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to Url rewriting for shared hosting of godaddy sub folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192410/how-to-url-rewriting-for-shared-hosting-of-godaddy-sub-folders)

Comment: We can only help if you exactly tell what is your requirement. Give us little more information

Comment: i have given in this post plz read .. i tried lot of code no code is working   see i just used    RewriteRule ^login\/index\.php$     /Subfolder/login/index.php [L]    here i am able to hide subfolder . subfolder is a link to another website . and when i write www.mysite.com/login/index.php in url the css which is in login folder for index.php is not working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# fix js/images/css
RewriteRule ^.+?/((img|css|js)/.+)$ /subfolder/login/$1 [L,NC]
```

Try adding this as your first rule in `htaccess`. Or you can use

```
# fix js/images/css
RewriteRule ^.+?/((img|css|js)/.+)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/subfolder/login/$1 [L,NC]
```

You can see more examples and ways of rewriting here: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/Rewrite

Comment: @user3555729 great to hear. Please upvote and also accept the answer on other page as well. :) cause half code is used form there. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add Another rule for css, or use absolute CSS path
e.g.:

```
RewriteRule login\(.*)\.css /subfolder/login/$1.css [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The title does not seem to match the question at the end of your description, but to answer the latter: If you have a problem with your assets (images, css, external javascript, etc.) after url rewriting, use absolute paths, for example:

```
/subfolder/login/style.css
```

instead of something like:

```
../style.css    /* this will probably not work when rewriting urls */
```

Comment: @user3555729 Where is the css file located exactly and how are you including it?

Comment: subfolder/login/style.css

Comment: RewriteRule login\(.*)\.css /Archana_Projects/login/$1.css [L]    tryed with this code it give internal server error

Comment: @user3555729 That's not an absolute path, note the missing `/` at the start. And there really is no need to use rewriting voor assets like style-sheets.

Comment: If you have any other solution for my problem in hiding sub folder..?